# Need to subtract one from user input. How? Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

basically I just need to know how to subtract one from a user input. I am trying to get an x and y coordinate from a user to place into a 2D array that can only be 20X20, so if the user puts in a 20, I need my program to read it as 19 so it is not out of bounds.

```
 x = keyboard.nextInt()
```

Is what I have now.

Comment: I tried that, but it immediately gives me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1"

Comment: Do you mean at the end as in not in the argument?

Comment: Yes, outside of the parameters

Comment: `int x = keyboard.nextInt()-1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
// solution 1
x = Math.min(19, Math.max(0, keyboard.nextInt() - 1));

// solution 2
x = keybord.nextInt() - 1;
if(x < 0) {
  // error?!
  x = 0;
} else if(x > 19) {
  // error?!
  x = 19
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I think I have an error elsewhere. No matter what value I enter for X or Y it comes up reading "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0" when the program tries to decide if the specific character is in the array at that position.

Comment: You should post a failing example snippet then.

Comment: Basically my error is when I am storing the user's character. My code looks like

Comment: System.out.println("Do you want to fire another shot? (Y/N)");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();
      answer = input.charAt(0);          The error is that the string index is out of range